# C++ property on class seems to be reinitialized

Tags: c++

In the class **Element**, i have a property called `size` with default value `0`.

When I call the `insertElement` on `main()` the line that calls `size++` works fine but, in the next line when function `shiftElementsToRight(i);` are called, the `size` element are restarted to `0`.

Why this happens? I'm declaring in wrong way my `Element` class?

Using g++ 9.2.1 on Ubuntu Linux

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int const ARRAY_MAX = 100;

class Element {
    public:
        int elements[ARRAY_MAX] = {};
        int size = 0;

    void shiftElementsToRight(int pos) {
        int temp = elements[pos+1];
        for (int i=ARRAY_MAX-1; i>=pos; i--) {
                elements[i+1] = elements[i];
        }
        elements[pos] = NULL;
    }

    void shiftElementsToLeft(int pos) {
        int temp = elements[pos];
        int i = ARRAY_MAX;
        for (int i=pos; i<ARRAY_MAX-1; i++) {
            elements[i-1] = elements[i];
        }
    }

    void insertElement(int value) {
        int i = 0;
        size++;
        while ((i<ARRAY_MAX) && (elements[i] != NULL)) {
            if (elements[i]>value) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        shiftElementsToRight(i);
        elements[i] = value;
    }

    int deleteElement(int value) {
        int pos = binarySearch(value);
        if (pos!=-1) {
            shiftElementsToLeft(pos+1);
        }
        size--;
        return pos;

    }

    int binarySearch(int value) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = size;

cout << "Begin" << endl;
        while (left<right) {
            int middle = left + (right -left) / 2;
            cout << "L: " << left << " R: " << right << endl;
            if (elements[middle] == value) {
                return middle;
            }
            if (elements[middle]>value) {
                right = middle-1;
            }
            if (elements[middle]<value) {
                left = middle+1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Element *element = new Element();
    element->insertElement(3);
    element->insertElement(2);
    element->insertElement(5);
    element->insertElement(6);
    element->insertElement(4);
    element->deleteElement(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
        for (int i=ARRAY_MAX-1; i>=pos; i--) {
                elements[i+1] = elements[i];
        }
```

Your first access to `elements` is at position `ARRAY_MAX - 1 + 1`. You're accessing `elements[ARRAY_MAX]`, which is outside the bounds of this array and (likely) points to `size`.